# TYPO3 Hook for Page/ Content

Tags: typo3, hook, typoscript, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I found [this Answer here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38132324/5516294).

I need a Hook, which is executed when a page and content is created, deleted, moved or updated. 
I only found this hook `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray` but it will not be executed if the content is created, deleted, moved or updated. It is executed only when a page is created or deleted.

I'm on TYPO3 Version 7.6.9.

Is there a list of all available hooks?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591992/typo3-extbase-individual-code-on-backend-deletion-of-an-object#answer-25600326). It has a detailed explanation on how to set up a hook that executes upon record deletion and will certainly help you out.

To sum it up, you need to register your hook in an `ext_tables.php`

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['YourHook'][] = 'YourVendor\\YourExt\\Hooks\\YourHook';
```

And declare the hook itself in:

```
/ext/your_ext/Classes/Hooks/yourHook.php
```

[Here is a partial list of available hooks from the official Docs](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_version_1_1_hook_1_1_data_handler_hook.html#ab753bdf58a8543ea194093e573e1abb0).

**Edit**

Your are looking for the correct [`Member Function`](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_version_1_1_hook_1_1_data_handler_hook.html).

To be honest, I am not sure if you need to hook multiple of them or if using `processCmdmap_afterFinish` will do what you need:

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExt\Hooks;

class ProcessCmdmap {
   /**
    * hook that is called when an element shall get deleted
    *
    * @param string $table the table of the record
    * @param integer $id the ID of the record
    * @param array $record The accordant database record
    * @param boolean $recordWasDeleted can be set so that other hooks or
    * @param DataHandler $tcemainObj reference to the main tcemain object
    * @return   void
    */
    function processCmdmap_postProcess($command, $table, $id, $value, $dataHandler) {
        /* Does this trigger at all for the actions you need? */
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($command);
        die();
        if ($command == 'delete' ||
            $command == 'update' || 
            $command == 'move' || 
            $table == 'tx_yourext_domain_model_something') {

        }
    }
}
```

*large portions of this code come from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591992/typo3-extbase-individual-code-on-backend-deletion-of-an-object#answer-25600326)*

Comment: I will take a look at it. Are these hooks just for page or both, page and content?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it tomorrow with the functions.

Comment: I tried the hook, but unfortunately only create and update a page are recognized. Is there a way to recognize create, update, delete or move content with a hook?

Comment: Best point to find out for yourself! Try to dump $command inside your hook like so: `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($command);`. See if it triggers on the action you like and change the `if` condition accordingly

Comment: With the help of the other hooks I got it to work . Thank you for your help.